# indentation error in python for raspberry pi

Tags: python, python-2.x

I am creating a motion sensor with my Raspberry Pi with python. I had this working fine to just print "motion Detected!", but now I'd like to add a feature to also take a picture. I am getting an indentation error on the line `camera = picamera.PiCamera()`. Removing this line causes an indentation error on the next line. What is going on here? Can my defined callback only be 1 line of code?

```
# coding: utf-8
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import picamera
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

PIR_PIN = 7

GPIO.setup(PIR_PIN, GPIO.IN)

filename = 0

def MOTION(PIR_PIN):

               print "Motion Detected!"
               camera = picamera.PiCamera()
               filename = 'image' + filenumber + '.jpg'
               camera.capture(filename)
               filenumber = filenumber + 1

print "PIR Module Test (CTRL+C to exit)"

time.sleep(2)

print "Ready"

try:

    GPIO.add_event_detect(PIR_PIN, GPIO.RISING, callback=MOTION)

    while 1:

        time.sleep(100)

except KeyboardInterrupt:

    print " Quit"

    GPIO.cleanup()
    enter code here
```

Comment: You're mixing spaces and tabs. [Don't](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces).

Comment: This is not Python 3

Comment: Also the error cannot be reproduced using the code you provided - please copy-paste correctly :D

Comment: Also you are using wrong tab-sizes, in Python 2 (as in here) tabs and spaces can be mixed but the tabstops are at 8 spaces. In Python 3 tabs and spaces absolutely cannot be mixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When looking at the indentation for the `MOTION` function, this is it (with tabs being visualized by `\t`):

```
def MOTION(PIR_PIN):

               print "Motion Detected!"
\t\t\t   camera = picamera.PiCamera()
\t\t\t   filename = 'image' + filenumber + '.jpg'
\t\t\t   camera.capture(filename)
\t\t\t   filenumber = filenumber + 1
```

As you can see, the `print` is indented with spaces, while the rest of the lines is indented with 3 tabs first and then 3 spaces. So the print and the following lines have a different indentation which throws Python off.

In Python indentation matters, and for a level of indentation, the indentation needs to be exactly the same. So if you indent with 15 spaces first, you need to keep that level for the whole function body.

In general, you should absolutely stay consistent in the way you indent: Either use tabs, or use spaces. Don’t use both, and especially not on the same line.

Comment: simple and effective. thanks

Comment: Or even better: never use tabs, period. It is new code here, so no need to start using confusing conventions.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala People are free to use whatever they want. Don’t turn this into a tabs vs. spaces discussion.

Comment: It can be pointed out that that discussion was pretty much [13 years ago](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces)